# Can I have $scope value in $rootScope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-rootscope

I have `scope` value which I need in `rootScope` so I can use it across app, and so I did it like

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.car= 'honda';
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.car= "suzuki";
});
```

I am accessing `{{car}}` in my index file and its giving me honda, that is fine.

What I need is same value of `$scope.car` in `$rootScope.car` to access it global as I wont be able to access $scope.car value.

The reason I want same value is in `$scope.car` , I will have my service value which is dynamically coming from json parse after long code  and to get in `rootscope`, to write service again is not a good practice.

Any other way, that In same controller function , I can have `$rootScope` just like `$scope` which I can use global ?

Or any other options ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you can use $rootScope, as every application has a single root scope. You don't have to have $scope.car in your controller, you can use $rootscope.car in your controller too.

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast a event  from your child controller

```
 $rootScope.$emit('eventname',obj)
```

and in the parent controller you can use

```
$rootScope.$on('eventname',function(event,data){
    console.log(data)
    })
```

this way you can access a variable in child controller to the topmost rootscope where eventname is any event you want to broadcast